# how to find missing number in a row in ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I have the below series:

```
REF NO
AI951
AI952
AI953
AI954
AI955
AI956
AI957
AI958
AI959
AI960
AI961
AI962
AI963
AI965
AI966
AI967
AI968
AI970
AI971
AI972
```

In above column series, **AI964** and **AI969** are missing.

To find those missing numbers in a row sequence in Access, what is the process? Do I have to write a query, or is there any predesigned tool?

Answer (score 2):

First, create a *Cartesian* (multiplying) query to generate all the numbers:

```sql
Select
    "AI" & CStr((Select Min(Val(Mid([REF NO],3))) From Samples) + [T].[Factor]) As RefNo
From
    (Select Distinct 
        [Tens]+[Ones] As Factor, 
        10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10) As Tens, 
        Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10) As Ones 
    From
        MSysObjects As Uno, 
        MSysObjects As Deca)  As T
Where
    (Select Min(Mid([REF NO],3)) From Samples) + [T].[Factor] <= (Select Max(Val(Mid([REF NO],3))) From Samples)
```

Save this as *AllSamples*.

Next, create a query to list the missing numbers:

```sql
Select 
    AllSamples.RefNo As [REF NO]
From 
    AllSamples 
Left Join 
    Samples 
    On AllSamples.RefNo = Samples.[REF NO]
Where 
    Samples.[REF NO] Is Null
```

Output:

[image]