# find missing number buckets

Tags: vba, ms-access

I was wondering if there's a better way

I need to find missing number buckets. There's a set of number buckets in which the weights are distributed. I want to make sure that if the user misses a number somewhere, his attention is drawn to it and hes told that he's missing some buckets, otherwise his data for these will not show.
I already found each missing number but it shows a line for each and the user is only interested in the entire bucket.

so, I need the thing on the left to become the thing on the right. The FROM and TO is what I have to work with.

I have a feeling there's some beautiful VBA solution for this, something with arrays :)

Besides all this ugliness that I wrote, to get the original missing weight, I had to create a table with all weights from 0 to 1000. there has to be a better way

```
Sub sbMissingBuckets()
 
    Dim vrQDF As Object
    Dim vrSQL As String
    Dim vrQueryName As String
    Dim vrCountsMissingBuckets As Long
    
    sbWOff

    DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE FROM MissingServicesShippingWeightBuckets"

    Dim vrRs1   As DAO.Recordset
    Dim vrServicesShippingWeightCollectionID As Long

    Set vrRs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT ServicesShippingWeightBuckets.ServicesShippingWeightCollectionID FROM ServicesShippingWeightBuckets GROUP BY ServicesShippingWeightBuckets.ServicesShippingWeightCollectionID " & _
                                        ", ServicesShippingWeightBuckets.IsMultiweight HAVING (((ServicesShippingWeightBuckets.IsMultiweight)=False));")
    
    Do Until vrRs1.EOF

        vrServicesShippingWeightCollectionID = vrRs1("ServicesShippingWeightCollectionID")

        vrSQL = "SELECT ServicesShippingWeightBuckets.ServicesShippingWeightCollectionID, AllWeights.Weight FROM ServicesShippingWeightBuckets " & _
                ", AllWeights GROUP BY ServicesShippingWeightBuckets.ServicesShippingWeightCollectionID, AllWeights.Weight, IIf([WeightFromInequalitySymbolID]=1,IIf([WeightToInequalitySymbolID]=3,[Weight]>[WeightFrom] " & _
                "AND [Weight]<[WeightTo]) & IIf([WeightToInequalitySymbolID]=4,[Weight]>[WeightFrom] AND [Weight]<=[WeightTo]) & IIf(IsNull([WeightToInequalitySymbolID]),[Weight]>[WeightFrom] " & _
                "AND [Weight]<=999999999)) & IIf([WeightFromInequalitySymbolID]=2,IIf([WeightToInequalitySymbolID]=3,[Weight]>=[WeightFrom] AND [Weight]<[WeightTo]) & IIf([WeightToInequalitySymbolID]=4,[Weight]>=[WeightFrom] " & _
                "AND [Weight]<=[WeightTo]) & IIf(IsNull([WeightToInequalitySymbolID]),[Weight]>=[WeightFrom] AND [Weight]<=999999999)), ServicesShippingWeightBuckets.IsMultiweight " & _
                "HAVING (((ServicesShippingWeightBuckets.ServicesShippingWeightCollectionID)=" & vrServicesShippingWeightCollectionID & ") AND ((IIf([WeightFromInequalitySymbolID]=1,IIf([WeightToInequalitySymbolID]=3,[Weight]>[WeightFrom] " & _
                "AND [Weight]<[WeightTo]) & IIf([WeightToInequalitySymbolID]=4,[Weight]>[WeightFrom] AND [Weight]<=[WeightTo]) & IIf(IsNull([WeightToInequalitySymbolID]),[Weight]>[WeightFrom] " & _
                "AND [Weight]<=999999999)) & IIf([WeightFromInequalitySymbolID]=2,IIf([WeightToInequalitySymbolID]=3,[Weight]>=[WeightFrom] AND [Weight]<[WeightTo]) & IIf([WeightToInequalitySymbolID]=4,[Weight]>=[WeightFrom] " & _
                "AND [Weight]<=[WeightTo]) & IIf(IsNull([WeightToInequalitySymbolID]),[Weight]>=[WeightFrom] AND [Weight]<=999999999)))=-1) " & _
                "AND ((ServicesShippingWeightBuckets.IsMultiweight)=False)) ORDER BY AllWeights.Weight;"

        vrQueryName = "qMissingBucketsBase"
        fnDeleteObjectIfExists "Query", vrQueryName
        Set vrQDF = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef(vrQueryName, vrSQL)


        'count qMissingBuckets
        vrCountsMissingBuckets = dCount("cTo", "qMissingBuckets")
        'if 0 do nothing
        If vrCountsMissingBuckets > 0 Then
            'loop thoruhg and onl add records to the table if the diff is more than 1
            DoCmd.OpenQuery "qMissingBuckets2"
            DoCmd.OpenQuery "qMissingBuckets3"

            Dim vrRs2   As DAO.Recordset
            Dim vrFrom As Long
            Dim vrTo As Long
            Dim vrDiff As Long
            Dim vrPlaceholder As Boolean
            Dim vrFromPlaceholder As Variant

            Set vrRs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("mtT")

            Do Until vrRs2.EOF

                vrFrom = vrRs2("cFrom")
                vrTo = vrRs2("cTo")
                vrDiff = vrRs2("cDiff")

                If vrDiff > 1 Then
                    If vrPlaceholder = False Then
                        If vrDiff < 99999 Then
                            DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO MissingServicesShippingWeightBuckets (ServicesShippingWeightCollectionID, ServicesShippingWeightBucket, WeightFromInequalitySymbolID, WeightFrom, WeightToInequalitySymbolID, WeightTo) SELECT " & vrServicesShippingWeightCollectionID & _
                                         ", '>=" & vrFrom & " and <" & vrTo & "', 2 as WeightFromInequalitySymbolID, " & vrFrom & " as WeightFrom, 3 as WeightToInequalitySymbolID, " & vrTo & " as WeightTo"
                        End If
                    Else
                        DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO MissingServicesShippingWeightBuckets (ServicesShippingWeightCollectionID, ServicesShippingWeightBucket, WeightFromInequalitySymbolID, WeightFrom, WeightToInequalitySymbolID, WeightTo) SELECT " & vrServicesShippingWeightCollectionID & _
                                     ", '>=" & vrFromPlaceholder & " and <" & vrTo & "', 2 as WeightFromInequalitySymbolID, " & vrFromPlaceholder & " as WeightFrom, 3 as WeightToInequalitySymbolID, " & vrTo & " as WeightTo"
                        vrPlaceholder = False
                        vrFromPlaceholder = Null
                    End If
                ElseIf vrDiff = 1 Then
                    If vrPlaceholder = False Then
                        vrFromPlaceholder = vrFrom
                        vrPlaceholder = True
                    End If
                End If

                vrRs2.MoveNext
            Loop

            vrRs2.Close
            Set vrRs2 = Nothing

        End If

        vrRs1.MoveNext
    Loop

    vrRs1.Close
    Set vrRs1 = Nothing
    
    sbWOn
End Sub
```

[image: example]

Comment: In your case, you could do a query that pulls From value from next record and if it is not equal to the To, you have a gap. But since you want to return both records, need to also pull the To value of previous record and compare with From. Review http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html#AnotherRecord

Comment: Finding gap in sequence is a fairly common topic, I saw a new thread on it just few days ago. Sorry, can't find again. Do research and when you have code with issue, post question.

Comment: hey, that's what i'm doing, using the previous record and i will post my code when i'm done but i thought there was a prettier solution. i often see people post few line beauties where i write a ton, figured i'd check if this one one of those

Comment: i know how to do it with queries and loops, i was checking to see if theres a better way, i specified that in my original post, i e, "looking for some kind of VBA with array type stuff". for some reason, i have a feeling this couldve been done with a few lines of code, was wondering how

Comment: I expect a query could call a custom function to return criteria to base filter on. Even the VBA would have to pull values from 'previous' and 'next' records to compare. That means manipulating recordset. Whether or not setting up and populating array would be helpful is questionable. As I said, common topic. Your question as presented is asking for code to be built for you, not improve code you already have.

Comment: i will post my code soon

Comment: posted my code, see if you can think of a better way. besides the way this is done (i don't like some parts), to get the missing weights for the screenshot, i had to create a table that has weights from 0 to 1000. such a bad way of doing things but i couldnt think of anything better

Comment: A similar method: [Find missing numbers in a field in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71202953/how-to-find-missing-number-in-a-row-in-ms-access/71203728#71203728).

Comment: yeah lol, thats what i did and i'm not sure i like it. but oh well, i guess this seems to be the only way